# VBScript: Open .dita file type

Tags: vbscript, dita

I am trying to open a .dita file (which I was hoping would launch my editor) through VBScript.I keep getting a Run Time error on this line of code:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "testfile.dita"
```

The every helpful error message is just "Error". I'm assuming it's the file type because it works with .exe and .txt files. Could anyone suggest how I'd fix this or offer an alternative please?

Comment: What's the editor of this .dita file ??

Comment: @Hackoo XMetal Author Enterprise 9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start testfile.dita"
```

Comment: That works, thanks! How would I pass a file path into that though? I want it to run a file from a file path stored in a variable.

Comment: please mark my answer as the answer for your question.. to pass the variable use `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start " & YourVariable`

Comment: Done, thanks.
This Is the code i have now. The file path is correct and the extra quotations allow spaces in the path, but nothing gets opened. Any ideas?
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start """&objPath&""

Comment: this will be a little dirty.. `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start """" """ & objpath & """"` or to have more clean code use `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c explorer " & objpath`

Comment: The cleaner one works perfectly, thanks for your time @Pupa Rebbe :)